# HTML CSS JQuery Fading/Appearing content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I simply want to have a certain portion on the page that swaps content in and out (lets say 3 different items), with a fade effect.  So I suppose I could define my container attributes for the content section, and then I could define each of the 3 div containers that will be swapping in and out.  So with that in mind, what code do I write to hide two containers and only ever show one at a time (with the fade effect).  This cycle would repeat forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) - this seems to cover most of what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are using JQuery with the following html:

```
<div class="container"><div name="1" /><div name="2" /><div name="somethingelse" /></div>
```

Then this would do the trick to fade everything out except the div named 2, which would fade in:

```
$("div.container > div").not('[name="2"]').fadeOut();
$('div.container > div[name="2"]').fadeIn();
```

You could easily make that a function that takes a parameter identifying the div to fade in, all others would fade out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to cycle forever, you can use a little dom manipulation to do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/S4UYA/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">content 1</div>
    <div class="content">content 2</div>
    <div class="content">content 3</div>
</div>
```

```
$("#container .content").not(":first").hide();

(function fadeItems(){
    $("#container .content:first").delay(1000).fadeTo(1000,0,function(){
        $(this).insertAfter("#container .content:last");
        $("#container .content:first").fadeTo(1000,1,function(){
            fadeItems();
        });
    });
})();
```